# Discribing quotient $\mathbb R/\sim$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $a \sim b$ iff $b - a \in \mathbb Z$. It's easy to prove $\sim $ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$. Then how do we describe $\mathbb R/\sim$ without having the definition of function? The problem is that the notion of function is not defined in my textbook yet so I can't use that and every related question I checked on here presupposes the notion of function.

The set $\mathbb Z$ is closed under subtraction, so $\mathbb Z$ must be one equivalence class. But how do we account for the real numbers?

For example, $0.9 - (-0.1) \in \mathbb Z$, so $0.1, 0.9$ must be in the same congruence class.

It's a question 1.6 on p. 8(p. 29 of the PDF) of the following book http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~acamer4/math300/aluffi.pdf

Comment: The quotient structure is essentially $[0,1)$ with addition modulo $1$. And this is (apart from length) essentially the unit circle, with the usual addition of rotations. Note the typo, it is $-0.1$ which is equivalent to $0.9$.

Comment: What do you mean by "describe" $\mathbb{R}/\sim$?  It looks like the author wants you to give a description of the resulting quotient space.  You can start by finding a set of representatives for the equivalence classes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can think of it as integral translates of the real line. I.e. pick your favorite $x \in \mathbb{R}$  and find $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is your class representative.

Comment: Can we say $\mathbb R/ \sim = \{[0, 1)\}$ since any real number is congruent to some element in $\{[0, 1)\}$?